# Increasing/Decreasing Font Size inside textArea using JButton

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jbutton

I'm creating a sticky note application using Java.

**What I want to do:**
I want to increase the size of the texts inside `textArea` each time I click on the increase size.
I will know how to do the opposite obviously.

**Short Code:**

```
        JButton incButton = new JButton("+");
        fontFrame.add(incButton);
        incButton.addActionListener(new fontIncAction());
        JButton DecButton = new JButton("-");
        fontFrame.add(DecButton);

        //textArea.setFont( Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, fz));
    }
}

private class fontIncAction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        textArea.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,20));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is purely a guess, but, try: textArea.setText(textArea.getText()) after you change the font. All that should do is reset the text. My hunch is that changing the font only applies to new text in the box. If this doesn't work, I can't help you. I just figured that a guess was better than silence :) Good luck!

Comment: 1) Use the current size of the Font as a basis for the new size.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) What exact problem are you experiencing in achieving the goal?

Comment: @CodyS, the font applies to the entire text. You don't have to replace the text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make the code more general you can do something like the following in your ActionListener:

```
Font font = textArea.getFont();
float size = font.getSize() + 1.0f;
textArea.setFont( font.deriveFont(size) );
```

Comment: wow! never saw something like this! what exactly is the `f` in `1.0f`  also what is `deriveFont`?  so `getSize()` returns the size of the font.

Comment: @iMohammad: See also [§3.10.2 Floating-Point Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.2).