# Changing Font Style when Clicking on a JButton Java

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jbutton

How to change the `STYLE` of the `Font` when clicking on a `JButton` ?

I'm trying to have 3 buttons each change styles to `PLAIN` or `BOLD` or `ITALIC`

I've read the `font Class API` but I there is nothing like `setStyle` we can only `getStyle`

I find font class in java is quite complicated more than it should :S.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675038/increasing-decreasing-font-size-inside-textarea-using-jbutton for a very similar question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would need to call `setFont(...)` not setStyle.

For example, if you want to keep the same font but change the style of a JTextField called "field" you could do something like:

```
field.setFont(field.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
```

**Edit**
To set the font to both bold and italic, you'd or the bitmaps:

```
field.setFont(field.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC));
```

Please note that this uses the bitwise inclusive OR operator which uses a single pipe symbol: `|` rather than the logical OR operator which uses a double pipe symbol: `||`.

Also note for further subtlety and confusion that `|` can be used as a logical OR operator, but you'll usually prefer to use `||` for this since the latter is a "short-circuit" operator in that if the left hand side of the expression is true, the right hand side isn't even evaluated.

Comment: awesome! so we have to `setFont` each time we want to edit any parameter. I tried to use the `deriveFont` before but I did not know how to use it. Now it's completely clear :) Thanks @Hovercraft !

Comment: I got a question, how about if I want the text to be `ITALIC` and `BOLD` ?

Answer (score 5):

you can do it as follow

```
JButton myButton=new JButton();
myButton.setText("My Button");
myButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
```

Answer (score 4):

Get the current Font, use [`deriveFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28int%29) to get a new Font similar to the current one but with a new style, and apply the new font.

Comment: Thanks :) I read it already before posting but it was unclear. thanks to @Hovercraft  his example helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you might look at the `StyledEditorKit` actions available to [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html). There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513) and a tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).