# Why JComboBox ignore PrototypeDisplayValue

Tags: java, swing, fonts, resize, jcombobox

In connections with these two post @iMohammad, 
[Increasing/Decreasing Font Size inside textArea using JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675038/increasing-decreasing-font-size-inside-textarea-using-jbutton) and
[Changing Font Style when Clicking on a JButton Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679088/changing-font-style-when-clicking-on-a-jbutton-java) ..., I'm facing with really funny issue that came from `JComboBox`by passing `setPrototypeDisplayValue` as an argument for `JComboBox's size` on the screen

please how can I resize `JComboBox` dynamically depends of `Font`, same as works correctly for another JComponents that I tried in my [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxFontChange extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JComboBox cbox = new JComboBox();
    private JTextField tfield = new JTextField("Change");
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Cash");
    private JButton button = new JButton("++ Font");
    private JTextField text;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public ComboBoxFontChange() {
        super("Combo Box Font change");
        text = (JTextField) cbox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
        cbox.addItem("Change");
        cbox.addItem("Cash");
        cbox.addItem("Font");
        tfield.setColumns(5);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Font font = cbox.getFont();
                font = font.deriveFont((float) (font.getSize2D() * 1.10));
                cbox.setFont(font);
                // EDIT
                cbox.setPrototypeDisplayValue(cbox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                tfield.setFont(font);
                button.setFont(font);
                label.setFont(font);
                //panel.revalidate();
                //panel.repaint();
                pack();
            }
        });
        //panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));
        panel.add(cbox);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(tfield);
        panel.add(button);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ComboBoxFontChange frame = new ComboBoxFontChange();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I debugged your SSCCE, and the value passed to `setPrototypeDisplayValue` is the empty string. Changing the line to

```
cbox.setPrototypeDisplayValue(cbox.getSelectedItem());
```

Makes everything work as expected. Removing the call to `setPrototypDisplayValue` also makes the program behave as expected.

EDIT:

The other problem is that no event is fired for the prototype display value because you set it to the previous value as before, and an event is only fired if the value actually changes. Adding `cbox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("");` before `cbox.setPrototypeDisplayValue(cbox.getSelectedItem().toString())` makes everything behave as expected, even on JDK 1.6. I agree that given that the font is changed, the preferred size should be recomputed, but at least this change is a workaround.

Comment: by mistake I edited wrong code lines, fast hands, now is correct as an example

Comment: Please explain what the program should do, and what it does instead. Everything seems to work as expected (JDK 1.7.0_02-ea).

Comment: :-) rest of us there are still in Java6, JComboBox still have same size on the screen

Answer (score 1):

I tried what JB Nizet said. But for me the comboBox size didnt change. How about you?

So i tried the following and the combobox size increased as i increased the font size.

```
cbox.setFont(font);
cbox.updateUI();
```

I also removed the line

```
cbox.setPrototypeDisplayValue(text.getText());
```

Comment: +1 works, but there are another issue, there must be `Bug`, since `updateUI(Look and Feel)` works as we expected, I think that this issue has nothing to do with update `Look and Feel `, strange

Comment: Don't use updateUI() method. That is for a LAF change. Changing the font is not a LAF change.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, a `GridLayout` and eight clicks gave this result on Mac OS X:

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
```

Combo: [image: combo] Popup: [image: popup]

As an aside, `cbox.updateUI()` restored the defaults prescribed by the Aqua UI delegate, `com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI`.

Comment: agreed that about FlowLayout and JComboBox

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code from the BasicComboBoxUI:

```
        else if ( propertyName == "font" ) {
            listBox.setFont( comboBox.getFont() );
            if ( editor != null ) {
                editor.setFont( comboBox.getFont() );
            }
            isMinimumSizeDirty = true;
            comboBox.validate();
        }
        else if ( propertyName == JComponent.TOOL_TIP_TEXT_KEY ) {
            updateToolTipTextForChildren();
    }
        else if ( propertyName == BasicComboBoxUI.IS_TABLE_CELL_EDITOR ) {
            Boolean inTable = (Boolean)e.getNewValue();
    isTableCellEditor = inTable.equals(Boolean.TRUE) ? true : false;
        }
    else if (propertyName == "prototypeDisplayValue") {
            isMinimumSizeDirty = true;
            isDisplaySizeDirty = true;
            comboBox.revalidate();
        }
```

For some reason a Font change only resets the "minimum size" not the "display size".