# How to make JComponent always fill parent event if parent is resizing or content of JComponent is changing?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JCombobox and I'm adding some items at runtime. Some of them are very long and my Jcombobox is growing very long too. It's in a JPanel container with BoxLayout (PAGE_AXIS). I have no idea how to prevent growing...
I wonder there should be a property like `overflow` and in combobox item will be shown like "123..." if it's "123456789".

**EDIT:**

I read your answers, thank you very much. But the problem is that my JPanel can resize and I need to make it's children **always** fill parent. So I cant set preferred size because my JPanel's size can change at runtime.
And I also can't set maximum size or use setPrototypeDisplayValue() because of the same reason.

I tried to use other layouts (GroupLayout, BorderLayout) but the result is the same.

I can post code if you want but I think it's not necessary. Let me know if you need it anyway.
Just tried with JTextArea with single row instead of JCombobox. Result is the same. It's growing when I type.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- I solved similair issue by overrode [JComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679421/why-jcombobox-ignore-prototypedisplayvalue)
- and there are two ways (as mentioned @Stas) resize JComboBox or its derived Popup or both together

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
myCombo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(myCombo.getHeight(), myCombo.getWidth()))
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple solutions for the problem. You can change layout to limit growing.

Or fix somehow max size of the combobox

Or add a custom renderer (extending default renderer) and set preferred size there.