# Java Layout Manager

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I use a grid layout of 2 rows and 6 column. the first column is a label and second is combo. My problem is

> according to the size of the label the combo box size also increases. 
>   i want a stable size for combo? which layout should i use?
>   I want a design like

**label1: combo1      label2: combo2     label3: combo3
  label4: text1       label5: text2      label6: text3 **

Comment: After combo3 all other were placed in a new line

Comment: the simple (though possibly not the one you want to hear :-) answer is: learn which LayoutManager does what, then choose which fulfills your requirement. The tutorial referenced in the Swing tag has a chapter on layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. for `GridLayout` you can use [JComboBox#setPrototypeDisplayValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679421/why-jcombobox-ignore-prototypedisplayvalue), then you can to set initial size for `JComboBox` on the screen very confortly
2. you can to use `SpringLayout` or `GridBagLayout`
3. use todays custom `LayoutManagers` as `MigLayout` is for example
4. notice about to choose the proper `LayoutManager`, everything depends of if the contents should or shouldn't be resizable with container

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over all Labels and set the biggest size to all of them.

```
Label 1             |________________|
Label Label 2       |________________|
Label Label Label 3 |________________|
Label 1             |________________|
```

Comment: what do you mean by "set .. size"? Typically, that's nothing the code does, as it's the task of the LayoutManager ... as you well know ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you have to code the layout by hand and no problem with using 3rd party libs, you might give [Miglayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) a try.

You could also use a graphical editor to layout your panel. There are two free tools that do a decent job (and I know of): The one shipped with [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) and the [Eclipse WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a GridBagLayout, setting the GridBagConstrints.fill to HORIZONTAL for the combo boxes

Answer (score 2):

In a `GridLayout` all tiles have the same size.

You should consider using `GridBagLayout`. You will also need to use a `GridBagConstraints` for each GUI-element to specify its position.