# Maintain JComboBox Size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox, layout-manager

I want to make an account screen for a project, but I'm still new to GUI's. This is my first time working with a JComboBox and I'm having a bit of trouble. I want to basically place the JComboBox inside a box, which will be part of my background image. I tried using BorderLayout, but that just made a giant combobox that took up my entire screen. I have [my code here](http://pastebin.com/U98ee1W1) and a drawing which illustrates my goal below: [image: My Goal]

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) for 2 layouts that can easily center the panel containing the combo box.

[image]

Use borders and layout padding within that panel for the white space required.

Comment: [use setPrototypeDisplayValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679421/why-jcombobox-ignore-prototypedisplayvalue)